# New Function constructor in Angular how to reference imported scripts in revived object

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have a json with function stored in it as strings and when I revive it using new Function and try to use the method which happens to use a library imported by angular like lodash I get a reference error. Here is the code the ZombieLoader will revive the json object and in the angular class test will try to run it i will get the error _ not found.

```
// This class takes a json and produces an object with methods
export class ZombieLoader {
  static revive(st: string): object {
    const result = {};
    const obj = JSON.parse(st);
    for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
      if (key.startsWith('@')) {
        result[key.substring(1)] = new Function('return ' + obj[key])();
        continue;
      }
      result[key] = obj[key];
    }
    return result;
  }
}

// the json with function in string form that will be hydrated back for use
{
script: '{"@run":"function () { return _.chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2); };}'
}  


// here I test the method which fails because it cant find _ 
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import {ZombieLoader} from './zombie-loader';

export class Test {
    constructor(script: string) {
         const sceneScript = ZombieLoader.revive(script);
         sceneScript.run();
    }
}
```

Why does the reconstructed object not have reference to Angular loaded scripts is there a way to reconstruct the object and bind it to an angular.
If I add the lodash to the index.html file it works but I don't want to have to do this to several other libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `()` at the end - `new Function('return ' + obj[key])()` you execute function and it can't be aware of any dependencies in its caller.

I dont know what `run()` does here `sceneScript.run();`, but `Function` constructor accepts arguments parameters, so you can just pass in needed dependency: `new Function('_', 'return ' + obj[key]);` and invoke functions later by passing that from the caller:

```
sceneScript.run(_);
```

Comment: sceneScript.run() is the revived object from the string with a method of run that just uses a lodash function imported by angular. I Just thought new Function can bind to this and use its imported libraries like so: var functions = ( new Function( scriptParams, script.source + '\nreturn ' + scriptResult + ';' ).bind( object ) )( this, _, momentjs, anotherImpotedlLib); apparently  not thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like _ library is not loaded by Angular because it is not used directly at the time of component creation . A small solution , try using _ library in constructor or Oninit like this 
`console.log(typeof _ );`
than you won't get reference error.